# jQuery autocomplete plugin not working in ajax loaded contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[jQuery Demo Page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

I am getting problem to get auto suggestion of country for contents loaded by AJAX. inside those ajax loaded forms.

I search to fix this problem everywhere but I get some post for auto suggestion form server. I am not using SERVER suggestion of jQuery autocomplete plugin.
Can somebody **solve this problem??**

```
/********************************** local start ******************/
var states = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
    'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
    'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
    'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#name1').autocomplete({
    source:[states]
});

$('#name').autocomplete({
    source:[states]
});
/*********************************** local end ***********************/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Gautam change this code

from

```
source:[states]
```

to

```
source:states
```

Comment: according to your suggestion i made change then all the country alphabets separated form each other and in ajax loaded content i am still not getting suggestion.

Comment: thanks @Rakesh fixed but ajax page problem is still there??

Comment: here is the link http://balajidesignwalls.com/ncrtaxi.com/ (you can check this in pickup point)

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept as right answer. I will check your ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102762/discussion-between-rakesh-sojitra-and-gautam-jha).

Comment: as per your suggestion `$('#name1').autocomplete({ 
source: states 
});` this code on ajax success working